# Setting control properties in PreInit() vs Init()

Tags: asp.net

As per MSDN, we should use `PreInit()` event to Create or re-create dynamic controls.

And `Init()` event should be used to initialize control properties.

My question is, will there be some issue if we initialize the control properties in `PreInit()` instead of `Init()`? If No issue, then for what purpose should we use the `OnInit()` event?

Below is the MSDN page life cycle link which states this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: You should show the link where it is mentioned that you should use `PreInit` instead of `Init` to recreate dynamic controls. `Init` is sufficient, in most scenarios even `Page_Load` is sufficient which has the advatange that you can evalute the `ViewState` since it's already loaded(e.g. if you use an `int` variable to store how many controls are already created).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: You can ignore that, i have never used `PreInit` for dynamic controls. That event has several disadvantages since you can't evaluate viewstate, you can't even set properties. _"If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event."_ (from your link)

Comment: Alright Tim, but this disadvantage is the case with Init() too. So does that means I should not use Init() either?

Comment: `InitComplete` allows to persist any values that are programmatically added to the ViewState collection.

Comment: Tim let me put it in this way: When should I use PreInit() and when Init(). I know preinit() is fine for loading MasterPage dynamically, but what about creating dynamic controls?

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that if your custom control builds its children in the **OnInit** stage and if it needs some data (property) to build those controls, you cannot assign that property from the **OnInit** stage of the page because the **OnInit** get called in the order from lowest leaf controls up the page.

Therefore the only place (in the code-behind) you can assign a property to a control which relies on some supplied data to build children in it's **OnInit** is in the **PreInit** of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your *Question 1*:

```
will there be some issue if we initialize the control properties in PreInit()
instead of Init()
```

In `PreInit()` event, controls are still not initialized completely, so it is not recommended to use this event to set Control properties.

*Question 2:* `for what purpose should we use the OnInit() event`

If question 1 is clear, then you agree that you will initialize Control properties in `OnInit()` as  also is said by MSDN.

Also, there is something important to understand about `Init` event and Control properties.

In `Init` you cannot access any controls properties after the last viewstate. Suppose you enter some text in a textbox control and click on a button control that makes a postback, now you want to view the value latest entered. In such case you will be able to see the textbox value which you’ve entered after `InitComplete` i.e. in `PreLoad`, since view state are loaded completely with `PreLoad` event onwards.

So, now you can say that if you set any control properties in `Init` event, there is possibility that it will be overridden when the next event `InitComplete` is raised & the  tracking of view state changes is turned on